# Distribution and moments of ratio of two beta variables?

Tags: probability-distributions

If $X$ and $Y$ are two Beta random variables, I am interested in the distribution of their ratio $X/Y$. More specifically, I am interested in the moment generating function of this ratio. There is a [paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610920008832632#.UntahHCtVAI) of Pham-Gia that apparently computes the distribution but I don't have access to it and I don't know how helpful it will be for determining the moment generating function. What is known about these?

Edit *(copied from comment added Nov 7 '13)*: I've located the paper, so now the only question is: what is known about the moments of this ratio?

Comment: I've located the paper, so now the only question is: what is known about the moments of this ratio?

Comment: Sorry - it might be a stupid observation, but I struggle to see how the above expression is correct. If we have $a=c$ and $b=d$, The first raw moment of the ratio should be 1.
And the above formula does not satisfy this. For example, for $a=b=c=d=2$ and $k=1$, I get: $$
\dfrac{B(2+1,2)B(2-1,2)}{B(2,2)B(2,2)} = 1.5
$$ What am I doing wrong? For the Euler Beta function I am using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the [scipy implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.beta.html)

Comment: @user14330 says; "The first raw moment of the ratio should be 1."   ... It appears that your hypothesis is that if $X$ and $Y$ are iid random variables, then $E[X/Y] = 1$. Unfortunately, your hypothesis is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OP wrote:

> what is known about the moments of this ratio?

I have not seen the paper ... but one does not even need to derive the distribution of the ratio in order to derive the moments of the ratio. In particular:

If $X$ ~ $Beta(a,b)$ and $Y$ ~ $Beta(c,d)$ are independent, then the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ is, say, $f(x,y)$:

[image]
[(source)](http://www.tri.org.au/se/Betajointpdf.png)

Then, the $k$-th raw moment of the ratio $\frac{X}{Y}$ can be derived immediately as:

[image]
[(source)](http://www.tri.org.au/se/kthmomentofratioofBeta.png)

where I am using the `Expect` function from the `mathStatica` add-on to *Mathematica* to automate the nitty-gritties for me (I am one of the developers of the former). If desired, one can express the solution slightly more neatly as:

$$\frac{B(a+k,b) B(c-k,d)}{B(a,b) B(c,d)}$$

where $B$ denote the Euler beta function.

Comment: I like this answer. Small followup Q. Presumably the (imposed) assumption about `k<c` is about higher moments not existing when the denominator has substantial weight on/near 0? i.e. If both distributions were the jeffrey's prior of `Beta(0.5,0.5)`, the ratio wouldn't have a mean that exists.